# Why is my css file not connecting to the html?

Tags: python, html, css, django

For some reason, my CSS code is not connecting with my HTML. I am not sure why this is happening what to do to fix the issue. home.html should be connecting to the CSS file main.css. I have added the static file block to the base.html and home.html since home extends base but the issue is still occurring.

base.html

```
{%load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TweetyBird</title>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css"  href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" >
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</head>
 
<head>
  
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">TweetyBird</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Company Registration</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Company Sign in</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/search">Search by Tweet <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    

      </div>

      
</head>
{%block staticfiles%}


{% endblock %}


  </nav>
  {% block content %}
  

  {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{%load static%}
{%block staticfiles%}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css"  href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" >
{% endblock %}
    
<body>
  {% block content %}

  <div class="banner">
          <div class="app-text">
          <h1>Text</h1> 
          <p> Text </p>
          
  </div>
  {% endblock %}

</body>
```

main.css

```
body 
{
background-color: lightblue;
}

.banner{
  width: 80%;
  height: 70%;
  top: 25%;
  left: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
}

.app-text{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.app-text h1{
  font-size: 43px;
  width: 640px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 40px;

}
```

Comment: You can look in the web server access log to see what css file the browser is actually requesting, which should provide a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your CSS file in a different folder from the HTML file? If so, you might want to `../css/main.css` instead.

Comment: For my other html files the css file is in a different folder but it still seems to be working. For example for base.html the main.css file is working properly even though its in a different folder. For some reason its not working for home.html

Answer (score 0):

Your **link** should be in head section. So, change your `base.html`. Here, it goes:

```
{% load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TweetyBird</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css"  href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" >
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        {% block staticfiles %}

        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">TweetyBird</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Company Registration</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Company Sign in</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/search">Search by Tweet <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

*Note:- There were some tags closed which was never opened like inner **nav** tag. Also, do not forget to use `{% load static%}` at the top of inheriting htmls.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem like two weeks ago. It's important to know which folder you are in. so, it's not working because the location  'css/main.css' is incorrect. try going outside of this folder, maybe back another folder and try looking for the exact location.